# Prove $T=T'$ using Natural Deduction.

Tags: solution-verification, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

Working on Lang, Serge. "Basic Mathematics" (p. 100, example).

> Let $S$ be the set of numbers x such that $1 \leq x \leq 2$. Let $T$ be the set of all numbers $5x$ with all x in $S$. We contend that $T$ is the set of numbers $y$ with $5 \leq y \leq 10$.

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\def\Ae#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ai#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall I} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ee#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ei#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists I} \: #1 \\}
\def\R#1{\qquad\mathbf{R} \: #1 \\}
\def\ci#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ce#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ii#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ie#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to E} \: #1 \\}
\def\be#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow E} \: #1 \\}
\def\bi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow I} \: #1 \\}
\def\qi#1{\qquad\mathbf{=I}\\}
\def\qe#1{\qquad\mathbf{=E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ne#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ni#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg I} \: #1 \\}
\def\IP#1{\qquad\mathbf{IP} \: #1 \\}
\def\x#1{\qquad\mathbf{X} \: #1 \\}
\def\DNE#1{\qquad\mathbf{DNE} \: #1 \\}
$
$
\fitch{1.\, \forall x(x \in T \leftrightarrow \exists y(5 \leq 5y \leq 10 \land x=5y))\\ 2.\,\forall x(x \in T' \leftrightarrow (5 \leq x \leq 10))}{
 \fitch{3.\, a \in T}{
   4.\,a \in T \leftrightarrow \exists y(5 \leq 5y \leq 10 \land a=5y) \Ae{1}
   5.\,\exists y(5 \leq 5y \leq 10 \land a=5y) \be{4,3}
   \fitch{6.\, (5 \leq 5k \leq 10) \land a=5k}{
     7.\,(5 \leq 5k \leq 10) \ce{6}
     8.\,a=5k \ce{6}
     9.\,5 \leq a \leq 10 \qe{}
}\\
10.\,5 \leq a \leq 10 \Ee{5,6-9}
11.\,a \in T' \leftrightarrow 5 \leq a \leq 10 \Ae{2}
12.\,a \in T' \be{11,10}
}\\
\fitch{13.\, a \in T'}{
 14.\,a \in T' \leftrightarrow 5 \leq a \leq 10 \Ae{2}
 15.\,5 \leq a \leq 10 \be{14,13}
 16.\,\exists y(a=y/5) \qquad?\\
 \vdots\\
 \exists y(5 \leq 5y \leq 10 \land a=5y)\\
 a \in T \leftrightarrow \exists y(5 \leq 5y \leq 10 \land a=5y)\\
 a \in T
}\\
a \in T \leftrightarrow a \in T'\\
\forall x(x \in T \leftrightarrow x \in T')\\
T=T'
}
$

I have three questions:

- Are the premises correctly symbolised ?
- How can I justify line **16** ?
- How can I complete this proof ?